# Global variable is not changing using _thread

Tags: multithreading, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I use a Raspberry Pi Pico W to control a LED Strip. On main thread I do networking, on the other thread rotate LED´s in a given interval. However, if I want to change this interval I have to terminate the thread and create a new one. Variable `rotate_isAlive` I set to False to terminate thread 2. I use the `global` keyword for this:

```
global rotate_isAlive
...
if (rotate_isAlive):
    rotate_isAlive = False

if rotation_direction == "right":
    # rotate right
    rotate_isAlive = True
    _thread.start_new_thread(do_rotate_r, (d,ltr)
else:
    # rotate left
    rotate_isAlive = True
    _thread.start_new_thread(do_rotate_l, (d,ltr)
```

In thread 2:

```
def do_rotate_l(delay, num_led_to_rotate):

while True:
    if rotate_isAlive == False:
        _thread.exit()
        break
    pixels.rotate_left(num_led_to_rotate)
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(delay/1000)
```

[YouTube suggests global variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1q0EaTkztIs), however my implementation doesn't work.

Comment: 1. It doesn't look like you've done anything to ensure the worker actually sees the `False` state before you set it right back to `True`. 2. If you changed how the worker handles the delay, you could do this without creating a new thread every time you want a new delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning what @user2357112 said into a full-on answer:

The very next thing that your main thread does after it sets `rotate_isAlive=False` is, it sets it back to `True` again.

```py
if rotate_isAlive:
    if rotate_isAlive = False
if rotation_direction == "right":
    rotate_isAlive = True
    ...
else:
    rotate_isAlive = True
    ...
```

Meanwhile, the `do_rotate` thread spends most of its time sleeping. The chance of it fetching `rotate_isAlive` during the fraction of a microsecond when `rotate_isAlive==False` is nearly zero.

You need to wait for the `do_rotate` thread to acknowledge that it saw the flag change. Since it reacts to the flag by dying, you can wait by `join`ing it:

```py
if rotate_isAlive:
    if rotate_isAlive = False
    do_rotate_thread.join()
...
```

---

But wait! user2357112 suggested a *much* better way to solve your problem: Don't *kill* the thread. Change it's "marching orders."

```py
global g_delay
global g_num_led_to_rotate
global g_rotation_direction

...

g_delay = ...whatever...
g_num_led_to_rotate = ...whatever...
if rotation_direction == "right":
    g_rotation_function = DIR_RIGHT
else:
    g_rotation_function = DIR_LEFT
```

And in the `do_rotate` thread:

```py
while True:
    if g_rotation_direction = DIR_RIGHT:
        pixels.rotate_right(g_num_led_to_rotate)
    else:
        pixels.rotate_left(g_num_led_to_rotate)
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(g_delay/1000)
```